# function that works on specific columns in arbitrary row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

How would one write a function in google sheets that would iterate over all the rows of a sheet. Within the current row, it would populate column A with the output of a math function applied to data in 3 other specific cells in the row (call them b,c,d even though they may not be in those specific columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. You can see usage in `example()`: `applyFuncToRowsWithIndexes` expects as the first argument your math function, then as argument 2 - 4, each of the three column indexes.

The math function, in turn, should expect a row as its first argument, and the indexes of the columns as arguments 2 - 4. The math function should update the row index 0, to update column A.

```
function example() {
  // Apply 'testMathFunc' to each row, with the three columns being
  // B, C and D (ie. index 1, 2 and 3).
  applyFuncToRowsWithIndexes(testMathFunc, 1, 2, 3);
}

// Function loops through each row applying specified function 'mathFunc' to each row
function applyFuncToRowsWithIndexes(mathFunc, colIndex1, colIndex2, colIndex3) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];

    // MathFunc should take 4 args:
    // The current row, and the indexes of the 3 columns used in the calculation
    mathFunc(row, colIndex1, colIndex2, colIndex3);
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}

// An example 'mathFunc' - testMathFunc, which makes column A simply
// the sum of B, C and D.
// Substitute with your own maths function
function testMathFunc(row, colIndex1, colIndex2, colIndex3) {
  row[0] = row[colIndex1] + row[colIndex2] + row[colIndex3];
}
```

Comment: In the docs it says a range can be a single cell or a range of cell. You treat it as if the range is the rows of the spread sheet. Why do the docs not say that, if that is the case? So getDataRange.getValues().length == num_rows?

Comment: A range can be either a single cell or a range of cells. `getDataRange()` retrieves all a range of cells for where there is data, which essentially brings back all the rows with data in.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of undefined.

Comment: The example assumed being executed from a script bound to a spreadsheet, such that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` would return a value. If that is not your use case, then alternatively you can use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` etc then select a sheet from there to use `getDataRange()` with etc.